Why list of replacement does not work in the following example?
I want to replace a long list but in the following format, but it does not work:
(Aa + Bb + Cc) /. {{Aa, Bb, Cc} -> {x + 2, y + 2, z + 2}}

(Aa + Bb + Cc) /. {Thread[{Aa, Bb, Cc} -> {x + 2, y + 2, z + 2}]}
